# how to add http connectivity Checker to Android app?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, androidhttpclient

I'm using Retrofit2 in my app and the problem is when my app is starting if app was unable to access internet, app will crash and terminate. so i've fixed this issues with connection checker, but it's only check if internet or wifi is connected or not.

How can i make my app to check http is access-able or not? i want in my app to show server is down for minutes, and stop closing app and make them use offline to get network access again. Like `whatsapp` when you're offline, you can open app.

Edit 01 : App Gain access to internet, then he want to get access to `php file` on server, but it's not able to access it, so i want my app check if `php file` is exist `http://simple.com/file.php` then continue and show contents, and if it's not exist show a toast message that server is not available now.

Comment: You can use the web-service for pinging.

Comment: `if app was unable to access internet, app will crash and terminate.` No need for crashes. You can catch exceptions or null pointers. And display a message instead. First resolve that.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for response, i'll do some research.

Comment: No need for research. Just debug your app and find out which statement makes your app crash.

Comment: @greenapps i said in main question man, the reason app will crash is, if client couldn't get access to php file, it's gonna crash. now what i wanna do is that i want to make app to check if file exist continue online if is not, continue offilne.

Comment: ??? You should find out why your app crashes. Which statement causes the crash. And then not execute that statement or so. You do some basic things wrong if your app crashes. So solve that first.

Comment: @greenapps ok man. thanks for response.